# Combining multiple cox models to present in a forest plot in R

Tags: r, cox-regression, r-forestplot

I have 6 different multivariate cox models which run different sub groups of a dataset with the same other co-variates that I am adjusting for the in the model. I would like to plot the hazard ratios of the subgroups in one forest plot from 6 different models.

I am using R

I can't find a suitable solution for this anywhere. Please help. I have looked into the metafor package and this doesn't seem to help. ggplot package doesn't seem to be able to combine different multivariate models.

Willing to try solutions outside of R also.

Comment: Hi Meercat. Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [minimale reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). That way you can help others to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Check out my `forestplot` [package](https://github.com/gforge/forestplot). This is exactly for what it was designed for. In particular you want the multiple confidence band section in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/vignettes/forestplot.html#multiple-confidence-bands).